# How can I get ConEmu to open more than 30 tabs?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, conemu

I have a .bat file which opens 100+ consoles, but I need them in new tabs.

Problem is, ConEmu has a max of 30 tabs. I can do this with regular cmd, but its 100+ new windows. I'd prefer them in tabs as it saves a lot of screen real estate.

If ConEmu cannot do this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How do you plan to manage so huge consoles amount?

Comment: Manage? These batch files each run something concurrently. As far as memory and CPU usage goes, I can get up to around 400 before running into some system problems. It'd be much easier to manage if they didn't cover my screen, rather in tabs :P

Comment: 400 tabs? You even will not be able to choose exact one. Moreover,  I think terminals based on "conhost.exe" will slow down your system with such large consoles amount.

Comment: Well, I do it on a daily basis. I'm not sure there is a way to run 100+ batch files in a single terminal at once? Or is there?

Comment: Also. May be you are going wrong way? 400 console windows is a great overhead... Why do not to run them concurrently in a single terminal?

Comment: I'm not trying to beat a dying horse; but there is almost certainly  a better way to go about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please vote for it at https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1779